# How to split an array according to conditional statement?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, signal-processing

I have a time signal (37913 ms to 40010) and I want to split it in every 20 ms gap.

For example for first 20 ms:

```
for t in time:
    if t>=37913 and t< 37933:
        list1.append(t)
```

This gives me the list `[37913.496549, 37916.878267, 37918.506757]`.

I want to make several different lists on every 20 ms gap. I know it should be really simple but somehow I cannot think of a solution.

****Edited****

So to further explain my point, what I actually want to achieve is that, have an incoming acceleration (with no upper time limit) signal **(Green Bars)** and I want to check if these incoming samples are in the range 0-20 ms, 10-30 ms or 20-40 ms and so on. If they are in such an interval then I have to approximate points **(black dots)** using this data. for example, if current values are in between 0-20 ms then I can use all of these values to approximate value at 10 ms by some approximation (let's suppose there is no current value at 10 ms). Approximation method is not important right now, I just want to capture these values

[image: example of image signal]

Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated thanks to all in advance.

Comment: Is it sorted by time?

Comment: use the range function and set the third optional parameter to the 20

Comment: You said "every 20 ms gap". What is the range of values in `time`? Do they start from zero? What's the upper limit?

Comment: @martineau it will be ideal if i can a solution without knowing the max value. To further explain my (actual) problem which might make it complex: basically, i have an incoming continuous acceleration signal, and i want to sample it after every 10 ms gap using e.g Linear Approximation. so for that first, i have to capture all acceleration values b/w 0ms to 20 ms to approximate 10 ms point.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What you happen when there's no signal at an exact XX ms time? You need to describe the input, processing, and desired output in much more detail.

Comment: @martineau i can explain by a graph should i post a new Question?

Comment: I don't think a new question is needed (yet). Add the graph to your question...it doesn't seem like more information could hurt (since you haven't gotten any answers you like, apparently).

Comment: @martineau i hope i was able to convey my point this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that I *think* does what you desire. To test it I had to create some sample input data since you don't have any in your question—which is what is going on at the very beginning of the snippet.

For each time range interval, it creates a separate "bucket" which contains the corresponding time values within the time range. **Note** that some time values may end up being place in two buckets since the interval ranges overlap.

```
from pprint import pprint
import random
random.seed(42)  # Create same "random" sequence each run for testing.

# First create some test data.
INTERVAL = 0.02  # 20 ms
start = 37913
times = []

nvalues = 2, 3, 4, 2, 1  # Number of values in each interval.

for i, nvalue in enumerate(nvalues):
    lowerbounds = start + i*INTERVAL
    upperbounds = start + (i+1)*INTERVAL
    for _ in range(nvalue):
        times.append(random.uniform(lowerbounds, upperbounds))

print('There are {} time values:'.format(len(times)))
times.sort()  # Put into ascending order.
pprint(times)

#=======
# Split the times up into "buckets" of values depending on their range.
HALF_INTERVAL = INTERVAL / 2
brackets = []
print()
print('Time brackets:')
st = int(min(times))
for i in range(4):
    begin = round(st + i*HALF_INTERVAL, 6)
    end = round(begin + INTERVAL, 6)
    brackets.append((begin, end))
    print(' ', begin, end)

buckets = [[] for _ in range(len(brackets))]  # Create empty buckets.
for t in times:  # Put each time in the cooresponding bucket of times.
    for i, (begin, end) in enumerate(brackets):
        if begin <= t <= end:
            buckets[i].append(t)

print()
print('Stored in corresponding interval bucket:')
for i, bracket in enumerate(brackets):
    print('bucket[{}]: range: {!r}, values: {}'.format(
            i, bracket, buckets[i]))
```

Sample Output:

```
There are 12 time values:
[37913.0005002151,
 37913.01278853597,
 37913.02446421476,
 37913.025500586366,
 37913.03472942428,
 37913.04173877665,
 37913.048438436395,
 37913.05353398975,
 37913.05784359135,
 37913.060595944386,
 37913.064372759494,
 37913.09010710576]

Time brackets:
  37913.0 37913.02
  37913.01 37913.03
  37913.02 37913.04
  37913.03 37913.05

Stored in corresponding interval bucket:
bucket[0]: range: (37913.0, 37913.02), values: [37913.0005002151, 37913.01278853597]
bucket[1]: range: (37913.01, 37913.03), values: [37913.01278853597, 37913.02446421476, 37913.025500586366]
bucket[2]: range: (37913.02, 37913.04), values: [37913.02446421476, 37913.025500586366, 37913.03472942428]
bucket[3]: range: (37913.03, 37913.05), values: [37913.03472942428, 37913.04173877665, 37913.048438436395]
```

Comment: this exactly answers my original question.Thanks. any idea what should i do if the length of time signal is now known?

Comment: SalmanShaukat: I'm not sure what you mean (assuming you meant "_not_ known"). The code from the `#=======` comment onward will work with a `times` list of any length. The code above that is just generating some data for testing.

Answer (score 1):

If your list of timestamps is sorted:

```
from itertools import groupby
sample = range(100)
INTERVAL_SIZE = 20
key = lambda x: x // INTERVAL_SIZE
list(list(v) for k, v in groupby(sample, key=key))
```

Will give you:

```
[
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
    [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
    [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59],
    [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79],
    [80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
]
```

If it is not sorted, add a sort (by `key`) before you use `groupby`, since it requires a sorted iterable.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this method:

```
 arrs = []
 while len(arr) > 20:
     pice = arr[:20]
     arrs.append(pice)
     arr   = arr[20:]
 arrs.append(arr)
```

you can make function out of it which gives you a piece each time you call it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you could use a range:

```
r=range(37913,40010,20)
```

output:

```
[37913, 37933, 37953, 37973, 37993, 38013, 38033, 38053, 38073, 38093, 
38113, 38133, 38153, 38173, 38193, 38213, 38233, 38253, 38273, 38293, 
38313, 38333, 38353, 38373, 38393, 38413, 38433, 38453, 38473, 38493, 
38513, 38533, 38553, 38573, 38593, 38613, 38633, 38653, 38673, 38693, 
38713, 38733, 38753, 38773, 38793, 38813, 38833, 38853, 38873, 38893, 
38913, 38933, 38953, 38973, 38993, 39013, 39033, 39053, 39073, 39093, 
39113, 39133, 39153, 39173, 39193, 39213, 39233, 39253, 39273, 39293, 
39313, 39333, 39353, 39373, 39393, 39413, 39433, 39453, 39473, 39493, 
39513, 39533, 39553, 39573, 39593, 39613, 39633, 39653, 39673, 39693, 
39713, 39733, 39753, 39773, 39793, 39813, 39833, 39853, 39873, 39893, 
39913, 39933, 39953, 39973, 39993]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using `numpy`, you can try this:

```
import numpy as np

#a = np.arange(37913,40010+1,1)
a = np.arange(0,10+1,1) # comment this and uncomment above for your case
nlen = 2
parts = np.array_split(a,int(np.ceil(len(a) / nlen)))
print("a = {}".format(a)) # [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]
print("len(a) = {}".format(len(a))) # 11
print("parts[0] = {}".format(parts[0])) # [0 1]
print("parts[-1] = {}".format(parts[-1])) # [10]
```

If you just want to break whole array into n parts, just do this:

```
nparts = 6
np.array_split(a,nparts)
```